# Why does Firebase Firestore not add any value to my database

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to add data to my new database but it does not work. I saw many questions but none of them worked. This is my code:

```java
FirebaseFirestore database = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

            isOn = !isOn;
            Toast.makeText(this, "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            database.collection("Hooter").document("A").update("value", isOn).addOnSuccessListener(value -> {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Success!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }).addOnFailureListener(error -> {
                Toast.makeText(this, "" + error.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            });
```

And then I get this in the logs:

> W/Firestore: (24.0.2) [WriteStream]: (d62ac51) Stream closed with status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=Channel shutdownNow invoked, cause=null}.

Why does this happen and how to solve it?

Comment: Have you tried to attach a listener to the update() operation, to see if something goes wrong?

Comment: yes. I tried onSuccess and onFailure listener and displayed a toast. But nothing comes up

Comment: Show us how exactly did you do that.

Comment: try using breakpoints and debugs in `onSuccess` and `onFailure`

Comment: I ran a similar snippet in my Android app and could not get this message. The `UNAVAILABLE` [error](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestoreException.Code#public-static-final-firebasefirestoreexception.code-unavailable) is often related to a network problem when connecting to Firebase services. Could you share your full log entry of this error? Are there any network connection issues where your application is running?

Comment: Those are logs, but in your code, you're using Toast messages. Is any of the toast displayed? If yes, what's the message?

Comment: no toast is not displayed even after 5 mins. I checked the network. It has a constant speed of 100+ mbps.

Comment: @ErnestoC there is a constant speed. Checked it out